# How to input a character in windows form application?

Tags: windows, forms, opencv

How can I input a character(name) in a windows form application textBox?

In C,

```
char name[256];

printf("what is your name: ");

gets(name);
```

In windows form application using C (I don't want to use C#), how can I do the same way?

```
name.Add(textBox1->text)??
name->Add(textBox1->text)??
```

Comment: Erm... Please can you format your question better?

Comment: Format question better? Em...I'm doing a GUI using windows form application. I want to transport my code to it. Some of it I might need to change such as above. I want to key in the name and then save it to txt file. Therefore, how can I do it in windows form using textBox?

Comment: "Windows Form Application", using C. What?

Answer (score 0):

- It is not reasonable to use **C** to to use .Net Windows forms.
- I don't know any modern GUI library for Windows that is pure C.
- There are plenty C++ native libraries to build Window GUI MFC, [QT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29)
- It is possible to use .Net Framework with C++ by using managed C++.

If you really want to go pure native C route... But here is link to start with Win32 programming: [Creating Win32-Based Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx)

Code like:

```
HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
    szWindowClass,
    szTitle,
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    500, 100,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's Win API. But I'm interested in windows form. If I'm not mistaken we can use windows form in C# language but we also can use it in C language also isn't it? Correct me if I'm wrong. From what I see, in C# we may use QueryFrame() but using C we use cvQueryFrame right? My problem now is that, how can I key in a name in the textBox and then there is a button save to save the name in a txt file?

Comment: Maybe you are talking about using managed C++ to use .Net Windows Forms, but it is unclear from your question (since you always say C, which is not C++). You should clarify your question. If you want to use .Net starting with C# and porting to C++ may be easier approach as you'll find way more samples to do things in C#.

Comment: Isn't printf is considered as basic C language and cout is considered as C++? That's what I learn from.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages , check on C and C++. Most likely you are always write in C++ with more procedural or object-oriented style... Saying "I need solution in C" limits possible answers as most general purpose libraries are  in C++.

Comment: In C:
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void)
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}

In C++:
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}
Have you check it? I don't think I'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure what you want to say. It is your question and no one knows what **you** need unless **you** clearly ask it. Right now the question is approximately "Native pure C solution for getting text from a text box (using windows forms)". which is pretty much impossible to answer positively

Comment: Alright. Actually I want to know how,
1. I have create a textBox.
2. Created a Save button.
3. How can I write in the textBox for every different peoples name and then click the button to  save it in .txt